# Почему статические переменные не сохраняют свое значение при выводе?

Tags: c++

Мне нужно что бы несколько переменных в классе задавались конструктором класса и сохраняли свое значение для каждого обьекта класса. Как я понял,для этого нужно использовать static переменные. Сначала я обьявляю их в header

```
private:
static  std::string Name;  //
static  float Price;         // обьявил приватные переменные
static  int Quantity;     //
```

Потом в файле класса

```
float SmartPhones::Price=0;
int SmartPhones::Quantity=0;
std::string SmartPhones::Name = "";
```

Далее определил конструкторы ,которые меняют их значение

```
SmartPhones::SmartPhones(int quantity)
{
    Quantity = quantity;
}
SmartPhones::SmartPhones(std::string name)
{
    Name = name;
}
SmartPhones::SmartPhones(float price)
{
    Price = price;
}
```

И конструктор который должен выводить их значения

```
SmartPhones::SmartPhones()
{
    printf("Class SmartPhones opened");
    if ( Price != 0 && Quantity != 0)
    {

        std::cout << "Name:" << SmartPhones::Name;        // получил доступ к значению приватной переменной используя публичную функцию
        printf("\n Price: %f", SmartPhones::Price);      // получил доступ к значению приватной переменной используя публичную функцию
        printf("\n Quantity: %i", SmartPhones::Quantity);  // получил доступ к значению приватной переменной используя публичную функцию
        printf("\n--------------------------");

    }
}
```

Проблема в том,что в итоге выводятся рандомные значения вроде -89081789798,причем при отладке видно что переменные Name,Price,Quantity имеют нужные значения. В чем проблема?
Вызов перегрузок конструктора

```
case 1: { cin >> Name;  SmartPhones(Name); break; }



  case 2: { cin >> price; SmartPhones(price); break; }                          

case 3: { cin >> quantity; SmartPhones(quantity); break; }
```

Comment: Я не знаю, что вам нужно, но описанное выше вам точно не нужно.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan По умолчанию да,но я последовательно вызываю его перегрузки до того,как выводить значения

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Добавил код в конец вопроса

Comment: Я не обратил внимание, что у вас статические данные, а вы говорите да

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Я отвечал "да" на то,что базовый конструктор ничего не обьявляет. Можете подсказать в чем я ошибку сделал? Уже все перепробовал...

Comment: Каждый вызов конструктора, это конструирование  нового обьекта.  Если вывод вы обеспечиваете в конструкторе, то всегда будете получать начальные значения. Я не понимаю что вы хотите делать, чтобы вам помочь. Вы сами не понимаете что делаете.  Я вам говорил, предоставьте код, и обьясните себе что значит в одном файле обьявлять закрытые данные класса, а в другом сам класс. Я ничего не понимаю

Comment: Никто не запрещает использовать конструкторы для изменения статических данных, но созданы они не для этого. Конструкторы создают новый объект и инициализируют его *нестатические* данные, а вы похоже делаете все наоборот: объект созданный не храните, а меняете статические поля. Поэтому все не понимают что происходит. Используйте уж тогда просто статические методы.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan У меня задание - использовать несколько перегрузок конструктора класса для изменения и вывода в консоль переменных класса. Вот я и пытаюсь сделать что-то такое

Comment: Какой-то странный у вас билдер :)

Comment: Вывод значений задание тоже через конструктор требует?

Comment: @trollingchar Точного требования нет,так что думаю можно и через обычный метод

Comment: С чего вы вообще взяли, что нужны статические переменные? *"сохраняли свое значение для каждого объекта класса"* Для меня звучит так, что нужны наоборот нестатические. Тогда требование использовать перегруженный конструктор становится логичным.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, Ну,я прочитал что статические переменные сохраняются в памяти и не меняются при создании новых обьектов класса. Вот и стал их использовать....

Comment: Мне кажется, что от вас хотят, чтобы у каждого объекта были свои значения переменных.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Нет,нужно именно конструкторы использовать,в этом и проблема.

Comment: Не понял. Я не говорю не использовать конструкторы. Я предлагаю использовать нестатические переменные вместо статических.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наверное вы хотели что то такого (обратите внимание, что  один из конструкторов имеет два аргумента):

```
class SmartPhones {
private:
    static  std::string Name;
    static  float Price;
    static  int Quantity;
public:
    SmartPhones(int quantity, float p)
    {
        Quantity = quantity;
        Price = p;
    }
    SmartPhones(std::string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
    SmartPhones(float price )
    {
        Price = price;
    }
    SmartPhones() {
        std::cout << "Class SmartPhones opened\n"
                  << "Name:" << Name
                  << "\n Price: " << Price
                  << "\n Quantity: " << Quantity
                  << "\n--------------------------";
    }

};

float SmartPhones::Price=0;
int SmartPhones::Quantity=0;
std::string SmartPhones::Name = "";

int main()
{ 
    std::string Name;
    float price;
    int quantity;
    std::cin >> price >> Name >> quantity;
    SmartPhones s1(price), s2(Name), s3(quantity, price), s ;
    // вот это последовательный вызов, а не создание временных обьектов
    return 0;
}
```

Ваши ошибки в том, что вы создаете временные(безимянные) обьекты, которые после выражения уничтожаются, и данные не меняются, но еще и вы перегружаете конструкторы с типами, которые неявно преобразются в друг друга. Например, как может компилятор понять, какой из конструкторов вы вызывать хотите этим: `SmartPhones(5)`?  `SmartPhones::SmartPhones(int)` или `SmartPhones::SmartPhones(float)`?.  То, что вы аргумент называете `price` ом, это ничего не значит... Вот почему при выводе вы получаете не то, что ожидали(хотя выводить куда то прямо из конструктора целесообразно разве что только в целях экспериментов) И так как нет полного кода, невозможно точно говорить о всех ваших ошибках

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, имеется в виду инициализация нестатических полей, которые у каждого экземпляра свои. Для этого конструкторы и применяют на практике. 
Если требуется определить несколько конструкторов, это не значит, что какие-то поля не надо инициализировать. Задача, аналогичная вашей, делается так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;


class xy {
public:
    float x, y;

    xy () : x(0), y(0) {}

    explicit xy (float angle) {
        sincosf (angle, &y, &x);
    }

    xy (float x, float y) : x(x), y(y) {}

    void print () {
        cout << "(" << x << ", " << y << ")" << endl;
    }
};


int main () {
    xy a;
    xy b(M_PI / 3);
    xy c(3, 4);

    a.print ();
    b.print ();
    c.print ();
}
```

Вывод:

```
(0, 0)
(0.5, 0.866025)
(3, 4)
```

Условия задачи вроде бы соблюдены: есть несколько конструкторов и переменные там изменяются. Вывод тоже есть. Вам осталось только сделать решение для своего класса на основе этого.

---

Если все же интересно про статические переменные, то они не привязаны к экземплярам класса, и обращаться к ним можно вообще не имея экземпляра: `имя_класса::имя_переменной`. *Очень редко* когда возникает необходимость обращаться к ним из конструктора. Из практики помню только один такой случай. Объекты в игре должны были иметь уникальный номер, причем чтобы можно было по нему сравнивать время их создания. Реализация:

#### entity.h

```
#ifndef UNTITLED1_ENTITY_H
#define UNTITLED1_ENTITY_H


class entity {
    static int next_id;
public:
    const int id;
    entity () : id (next_id++) {}
};


#endif //UNTITLED1_ENTITY_H
```

#### entity.cpp

```
#include "entity.h"

int entity::next_id = 0;
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "entity.h"

using namespace std;


int main () {
    entity player, mob1, mob2;
    cout << player.id << " " << mob1.id << " " << mob2.id << endl;
}
```

Вывод:

```
0 1 2
```

Comment: Почему вы решили, что делается именно так?  Вы просто предложили свой вариант, но делается совсем по разному. И вообше, любую задачу можно решать многими способами (особенно  такую задачу )